# What is the correct way to register generic type to spray-json-support in akka-http Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, akka, akka-http, spray-json

So, I have this class:

```
case class Something[T](data: Option[T] = None)
```

And i register it like the instruction said in https://github.com/spray/spray-json and in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html. Like this:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

trait InternalJsonFormat extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
    import spray.json._

    implicit def somethingFormat[A :JsonFormat] = jsonFormat1(Something.apply[A])
}
```

And last i used `complete` from akka http directive. Like this:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

object ResponseIt extends InternalJsonFormat {
    def apply[T](rawData: T) = {
        val theResponse = Something(data = Some(rawData))
        complete(theResponse)
    }
}
```

And then i get an error in `complete(theResponse)`. It said

```
Type mismatch, expected: ToResponseMarshallable, actual: Something[T]
```

===========================================================

I have try to edit the last code for debugging purpose, like this:

```
object ResponseIt extends InternalJsonFormat {
    import spray.json._

    def apply[T](rawData: T) = {
        val theResponse = Something(data = Some(rawData))
        val trying = theResponse.toJson
        complete(theResponse)
    }
}
```

and get new error in `val trying = theResponse.toJson`. like this:

```
No implicits found for parameter writer: JsonWriter[Something[T]]
```

So, i really confused what is wrong in my code?. Is there any correct way to use the spray json support in akka http?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see, there is no evidence for existence of `JsonFormat` for your `T` here:

```
 def apply[T](rawData: T) = {
        // ^--- here
        val theResponse = Something(data = Some(rawData))
        val trying = theResponse.toJson
        complete(theResponse)
    }
```

One can rewrite this method to provide `JsonFormat` for generic `T`:

```
def apply[T](rawData: T)(implicit formatter: JsonFormat[T])
```

Comment: thanks for answering :) . but, i get a new error for that, it said `Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for Something[_1]`

Comment: Hm. What is `_1` type and do you have JsonFormat for it? Also, you can provide a minimal reproducible example of code that does not compile, so I or others can take a look.

Comment: Wah Thanks you so much @Yevhenii Popadiuk. I'm sorry.. actually i have 2 field in `Something` like this `case class Something[T](data: Option[T] = None, meta: Option[String] = None)`.. and in the last code i have this `val theResponse = if (blabla) Something(data = Some(data)) else Something(meta = Some(meta))` and that is the cause of the problem. I should have make it explicit assignment.. hehe Thanks you so much :)